# python setup.py install - fails with error 5: permission denied

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cython, setup.py

I downloaded under Windows 7 a new package and tried to install with “python setup.py install -i”.
Result: **[Error 5] permission denied**.

[Similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349217/cant-execute-setup-py-error-5-access-denied) in stackoverflow did not help: The permission settings of the folders are ok. I gave full access to all users. See also below.

Result of my analysis: **“install” uses “build_ext”, which causes the error**.

Therefore I have built a very small example to debug this error in following sequence:

1) I Created directory *C:\hello_world* with 2 files:

helloworld.pyx

```
print "Hello World"
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)
```

The directory has full set of rights for all users.

2) Then I used anaconda console executed in administrator mode (I tried also the DOS box) :

```
C:\hello_world>python setup.py build_ext -i

Compiling helloworld.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing helloworld.pyx
running build_ext
building 'helloworld' extension
error: [Error 5] Zugriff verweigert  // translated: permission denied
```

The build failed. But the directory  *C:\hello_world*
has now three files and includes:  *helloworld.c* with reasonable content.
This means: It was possible to write into this directory.

3) I added a log.info to the file build_ext.py to find out, where the pyd-file will be stored: Line 463 of build_ext.py is now: 
*`log.info("building '%s %s' extension", ext.name, ext_path)`*

Next trial on the anaconda console:

```
C:\hello_world>python setup.py build_ext -i

running build_ext
building 'helloworld C:\hello_world\helloworld.pyd' extension
error: [Error 5] Zugriff verweigert  // translated: permission denied
```

At this state I don't know what to do. My personal believe is that error 5 is issued by the microsoft visual C++.

Can please somebody help?

P.S.: I use Windows 7 and ..
Python 2.7.10, 
Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit), 
Cython 0.22.1, 
setuptools 17.1.1, 
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 (needed because of vcvarsall.bat)